# How to set a default value for a Django Form Field, that would be saved even in the absence of user initiated changes?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When looking for this feature, one is flooded under answers pointing toward the Form `initial` member.

Yet, by its design, this approach would not save anything to database if the user does not change at least one value in the form, because the `has_changed` method returns `False` when only initial values are submitted.
Then, if one were to override `has_changed` to always return true, the behaviour would be to try to save forms for which no value (nor initial nor user input) is found.

Is it possible to have a real default value in Django: a value that the user can change if he wants, but that would still save the form to DB when the form is only submitted with default values ?

Comment: Are you looking for [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#default)?

Comment: @Sayse Thank you for your suggestion. I would be looking for something that acts on Form Fields, not on Model Fields.

Comment: How about overriding is_valid() in you form?

Comment: @PhoebeB Could you please give further details on how one could achieve defaults values by changing the form's `is_valid()` ?

Comment: I'm assuming you display a form with default values in it?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#initial and you can then check in is_valid() that the defaults are valid?

Comment: Or override has_changed to True and do the checking in the save method of the model?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the *solution* I am currently using to replace the meaning of `initial` to achieve the behaviour described in the question. I override the `had_changed` method of the `Form` to be:

```
def has_changed(self):
    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        prefixed_name = self.add_prefix(name)
        data_value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, prefixed_name)

        if data_value and not issubclass(field.__class__, forms.models.InlineForeignKeyField):
            return True
    return False
```

The second check (`issubclass(...)`) is required in case the `Form` is used in an `InlineFormset`: when **editing** the parent model, the foreign_key field is automatically populated for all forms displayed (even the ones that have no default values), so it prevents saving the ones that are left blank (neither defaults nor user input).

---

Now, on a personal and probably polemic note, I must say I hope I missed something obvious. My requirements seem quite basic, yet the solution here is nothing short of a brittle hack...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a premade solution for you.  You'll have to do one of two things:

1. When the form is submitted, examine the value of the field in question.  If it is equal to the default value, then ignore the result of `has_changed` and save it.  (Be aware that this could result in duplicate items being saved, depending on your schema.)
2. When the form is submitted, search for an existing record with those field values.  If no such record exists, save it.  Otherwise do nothing.  (If these records contain a last-updated timestamp, you might update that value, depending on your application.)